# How to convert "商品编号" to "\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

`"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"` is displayed as `"商品编号"`.

```
"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7" # => "商品编号"
```

What is the character encoding in `"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"`? How can I convert `"商品编号"` to `"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"`?

Comment: HEI,  what's your problem .   The question is how to convert , is not about displayed

Comment: you can't  convert `"商品编号"` to `"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"` because are the same strings, for the second is just visual represenation of the first.

Comment: Note "What is the character encoding in `"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"`?" has an answer: "Any Unicode-supporting encoding, but probably UTF-8 by default in Ruby". That is because what you are seeing *isn't* an encoding per se, but a convenient representation using escape sequences. To find the encoding being used, you can write `"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7".encoding`, but do note the escape sequence would look exactly the same in all the Unicode-based encodings supported by Ruby.

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ. Thanks for your reply.   Perhaps parse better than convert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\uHHHH` (where `HHHH` is in hex) notation is simply a way to reference Unicode characters by number. This is usually used when:

1. You don't know how to get things like `商` out of your keyboard.
2. You're working in an environment that can't display all the Unicode that you need.

When you say `"\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7"` and see `"商品编号"`, it simply means that you're working in a modern terminal that is Unicode aware and has a good font.

In most cases it should matter which representation you use, it all ends up as the same bytes inside the machine. However, if you must get the `\u` version for some reason, then you can say things like this (assuming that your encoding starts out right):

```
ascii_friendly = str.chars.map { |c| '\u%4.4x' % c.ord }.join
```

Then when you print `ascii_friendly` to the screen, a file, or say a JSON stream, you'll see things like

```
\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7
```

Note that the `\u5546` in there is not the single Unicode `商`, it is the six characters `\`, `u`, `5`, `5`, `4`, and `6`. If your target is JSON, then the `\u` escapes will be interpreted properly when the JSON is parsed but if your target is anything else, it will just see the six characters rather than the single Unicode character you're looking for.

Comment: @2g. mu is too short may be explaining it better, and I don't object this being a good answer, but it is saying the same thing as my answer, as well as Малъ Скрылевъ's comment.

Comment: @sawa. All right! Please forgive me.